# Pandas concatenating dataframes raises ValueError

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am looping through many smaller dataframes and concatenating them into a single dataframe using `pandas.concat()`.  In the middle of the looping an exception is raised with message `ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned`.

The failed dataframe contains a single row (like all the previous dataframes) and the columns are a subset of the other dataframe. A sample snippet of the code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
df, failed = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
for _file in os.listdir(file_dir):
    _tmp = pd.read_csv(file_dir + _file)
    try:
        df= pd.concat([df, _tmp])
    except ValueError as e:
        if 'Plan shapes are not aligned' in str(e):
            failed = pd.concat([failed, _tmp])
print [x for x in failed.columns if x not in df.columns]
print len(df), len(failed)
```

And I end up with the result

```
Out[10]: []
118 1
```

Checking the failures it is always the same dataframe, so the dataframe must be the problem. Printing out the dataframe I get

```
0           timestamp    actual average_estimate median_estimate  \
0 1996-11-14 01:30:00  2.300000         2.380000       2.400000   

0       estimate1       estimate2      estimate3      estimate4   \
0        2.400000        2.200000       2.500000       2.600000   

0       estimate5 
0        2.200000
```

Which has a similar format to the other concatenated dataframes and the `df` dataframe. Is there something that I'm missing?

Extra info: I am using pandas 0.16.0

Edit: full stack trace below with modifications for anonymity

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<environment>\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-48539cb93d64>", line 37, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([df, _tmp])
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<environment>\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 755, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<environment>\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 926, in get_result
    mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.axis, copy=self.copy)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<environment>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4040, in concatenate_block_managers
    for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<environment>\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4258, in combine_concat_plans
    raise ValueError("Plan shapes are not aligned")
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Edit 2: Tried with 0.17.1 and 0.18.0 and still have the same error.

Comment: @Alexander I have added the full stack trace.

Comment: It would be useful to know `df.shape` and `failed.shape`.  You may need to upgrade your version of pandas and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: `df.shape` produces `(118, 65)` and `failed.shape` produces `(1, 9)` which are both expected.

Comment: Looks like index is repeated at both column header and data row.

Comment: @Hun repeating the code but setting the `ignore_index` flag to `True` still fails.

Comment: Try this: _tmp = pd.read_csv(file_dir + _file); print _tmp.columns; and see when columns change, and also see when you get the error.